# What data i can save?

Tags: json-rpc, php

i'm make one application about bitcoin, and I'm searching that data i can save, I'm read that the public key i can save in my database and privit key no, but i dont know, what more data i can save, I explain?, I'm would like to guide me, I have also read about getblock, but I don't know what it really is.

To be more specific, I would like to know exactly what data I have to save in the database and what performs each of the aforementioned functions of bitcoin.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Why do you want to save data in your database?

Your answer doesn't explain why but the answer can have a pattern, described below

> When I need to store additional information when I use bitcoin RPC

In general, you don't need to store additional information from the DB, for instance, you don't need to store the block in your DB (I hope if you don't want pass all the life to see your script make insert on the database) because Bitcoin core use the DB to indexed each block and get the data back when you will ask some block.

There are special cases when you need to save the data, for example, you are doing your personal web wallet for fun (I did with c-lightning) and what has a different wallet, and maybe you want to store the name (it is called wallet_name) of the last wallet that is using, or maybe you want to save additional information, as the name of a special address that you generated to receive some donation.

In conclusion, with Bitcoin RPC you have the access to the Bitcoin core node and you have the power to do all things that you want, but maybe you can use your application to learn how bitcoin work and if it is a good idea store data locally from bitcoin network.

> I have also read about getblock, but I don't know what it really is.

You can start to read how bitcoin work with [this good resource](https://github.com/bitcoinbook/bitcoinbook) (In my opinion).

Comment: Thanks to answer my question, i need save the data in my database because is more fast to return data in my application, but thanks very much.